# Can't get data from Firestore using pure PHP and REST API

Tags: php, google-cloud-firestore

So, after spending ~4 hours trying to get data from a Firestore database, I've ended up with this code:

```php
$firestoreUrl = 'https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/[MY-PROJECT-ID]/databases/(default)/documents/users';

$query = http_build_query([
    "structuredQuery" => [
        "select" => [
            "fields" => [
                "fieldPath" => "email"
            ]
        ],
        "where" => [
            "fieldFilter" => [
                "field" => [
                    "fieldPath" => "email"
                ],
                "op" => "EQUAL",
                "value" => [
                    "stringValue" => "test@gmail.com"
                ]
            ]
        ],
        "from" => [
            "collectionId" => "users"
        ]
    ]
]);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $firestoreUrl . $query);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Authorization: Bearer [MY-ACCESS-TOKEN]']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

echo curl_exec($ch);
```

and the response is:

`{}` with `HTTP/2 200`.

When I remove the `$query` from the curl url, I'm getting the whole records of the database.

I've also tried to use `json_encode()` on `$query`, but nothing happens as well. Still getting this `{}` with `HTTP/2 200` response.

Any help?

Comment: Is using the Cloud Firestore REST API a _requirement_ for you? Please know that you can use Firestore client libraries (includes PHP) to get a snapshot of your database data. Refer to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) for more details.

Comment: @sllopis Ok, I decided to use Google's official library. Thanks...

Comment: @sllopis Is it possible to detect concurrent write and stop the request? I really need to stop if someone already writing to the document.

Comment: You didn't _have_ to switch, I was just asking in case you weren't aware of it. I'm not sure what you mean by "detecting a concurrent write and stop the request", but note that you can [update your data with transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions). This means that if a transaction reads documents and another client modifies any of those documents, Cloud Firestore retries the transaction. This feature ensures that the transaction runs on up-to-date and consistent data. Refer to the documentation for more details.

Comment: @sllopis I need to return an error message if two users are trying to update the same field in a document. If `user A` updates some field in `document X`, and `user B` tries to update the same field, `user B` will receive an error. In Realtime Database we can achieve that by using an ETag. If ETage mismatches (which means that there is a concurrent request), Realtime Database returns 412 code. I'm asking if there is something similar in Firestore.

Comment: Okay, Firebase Realtime database is _not_ the same as Cloud Firestore, they are distinct products and don't share the same characteristics. I think that for this particular case Firestore transactions can prevent concurrent writes to your database. Perhaps, this can give you a more elaborated answer to your question [Firestore what happens when an offline device goes online?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51083190/firestore-what-happens-when-an-offline-device-goes-online).