# Firestore cache data before restarting app

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have no code but only a special question regarding Cloud Firestorage by Google.

Im using currently a listener for my Firestorage within my react-native-app which I also use expo for.
I know that as long as I stay in the app and tab out of the window, all data downloaded by the listener is getting stored in a temporary cache so when I come back to the screen with the listener, the listener doesnt need to download all data again but rather the missing sample.

My question would be: Does this also apply if I close the app entirely, for example for multiple days so that my token for authentification expires and I need to log myself in again into the app or rather into my Firebase?

(I want to prevent downloading all data the listener points to only because I restarted the app.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52912231/5519300) the `firestore` persistance for the web is `disk persistance` so it survies App and devices restarts. Multiple days should also be fine.

I have a Web App tha is using `firestore` and very heavily offline capabilities. We never had issues with that.

Comment: The part about disk persistence was what I was interested in, thank you for your answer!